# Trying to add +1 value in a attribute - Roblox Luau

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I was trying to make a code that if you touch a coin, then the value of your coins goes up 1 more, but i tried to make and haven't sucess. Here's the code.

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(Player)
if Player.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
    local Players = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Player.Parent)
    local Money = Players:GetAttribute("Coin")
    Players:SetAttribute("Coin", +1)
    task.wait(.2)
    script.Parent:Destroy()
end end)
```

Comment: You should include an error if you are getting one, you code has invalid you should be getting an `unexpected symbol near '+'` error. simply saying "my code doesn't work" but not explaining what that means is not helpful, imagine if you were to get a response equally as vague "yep something is clearly wrong in it"

Comment: I know that gives an error, sorry for putting this on code, but i dont know how to make this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll want to add your previously amount + 1

```
local Money = Players:GetAttribute("Coin")
Players:SetAttribute("Coin", Money+1) -- Add Money + 1
```